# How to read and write from datatap using Tensorflow on BlueData?

Tags: python, tensorflow, bluedata

I want to be able to use BlueData's [datatap](https://bluedata.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/220223188-DataTap-Overview) directly from TensorFlow.

With pyspark, I can do something like this:

```
df.write.parquet('dtap://OtherDataTap/airline-safety_zero_incidents.parquet')
```

Note that I don't need to set up any libraries - it's ready to go out of the box.

What do I need to do for reading/writing data over DataTap from Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs: http://docs.bluedata.com/40_datatap-tensorflow-support

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.python.framework.versions import CXX11_ABI_FLAG

CXX11_ABI_FLAG

bdfs_file_system_library = os.path.join("/opt/bluedata","libbdfs_file_system_shared_r1_9.so")
tf.load_file_system_library(bdfs_file_system_library)

with tf.gfile.Open("dtap://TenantStorage/tmp/tensorflow/dtap.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write("This is the dtap test file")

with tf.gfile.Open("dtap://TenantStorage/tmp/tensorflow/dtap.txt", 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
```